# C++ Compiler flags in AIX: -qlanglvl=newexcp works unless I add -q64 for 64bit compiling - why?

Tags: aix, flags

So I'm adding an exception to an existing project but have run into an issue.  I have the following compiler flags:

```
OC_COMPFLAGS =  -c $(OC_DEBUG_COMPFLAGS) **-q64** -qcpluscmt -qinitauto=00 $(OC_OPT_COMPFLAGS) -D_RWCONFIG_8d -DXML_LIBRARY **-qlanglvl=ansifor:newexcp** -qlonglong -qfuncsect -bnoquite -bloadmap -qnamemangling=v8
```

The newexcp flag works perfectly except when we add in the -q64 flag - at which point it stops working.  Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what "it stops working" means.

Comment: Sure - as a test, I've added a try/catch and just try to allocate a huge amount of memory.  Without the -q64, I catch (bad_alloc & e), but with it, the exception is never thrown.

Comment: How big is "huge"? Could it be that the allocation is just succeeding? And what language are you using?

Comment: No chance - it's in a while(true) loop continuously doing int * a = new int[1000];  Using C++.

Comment: It might still take a long time before it fails.  Some systems overcommit memory, particularly Linux; I don't know whether that applies to AIX.  Try doubling the allocation size on each iteration of the loop.  Or append each allocation to a linked list; it's possible that the compiler recognizes that you're not using the allocated memory.

Comment: When compiling as 64bit you have a *way* bigger address space, so you might not run out of address space in reasonable time. Does the `new` produce pointers that look valid?

Comment: I've tried changing my program to new int[1000000], but this just continues for a really long time again.  When I do topas, it shows the PgSp growing to about 16GB

Comment: As I said, try doubling the allocated size on each iteration. This should get you up to a size that can't be allocated very quickly, and demonstrate whether `new` throws an exception when it fails.  Print the size before attempting the allocation. (If it seems absurdly large, that would be a separate issue.) Use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` for the allocation size.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot.  Something I noticed yesterday was, if I limit the size of my exe to 2GB (through bmaxdata), it throws the exception I want immediately - it cannot allocate that big of a chunk at one time I assume.  However, if it's unlimited, then it continues to run for a really long time.  Could the page file come into play at all here?

Comment: Yes.  If the paging space is growing you are paging out to disk.  You could run vmstat while you execute to see that activity as well.  A 32 bit app has (usually) one 2^24 bit segment for the heap.  A 64 bit app has 2^36 segments (minus a few).  You can also set ulimit to something small and force a limit on the size of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

This might be applicable - from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IY20996:

"The user can get new to throw exceptions by adding the following call to their program:
  __set_new_throws_exception(true);